# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present on requested resource - SEMrush API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, cors

I'm trying to use SEMrush API, I make a request in jQuery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(
        'https://api.semrush.com',
        {
            type: 'phrase_this',
            key: 'XXXXXXXXX',
            phrase: 'lol',
            database: 'uk'
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And that is the result:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.semrush.com/?type=phrase_this&key=XXXXXXX&phrase=lol&database=uk' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Looking around stack overflow I found a lot of people having different questions about this API which leads me to believe that there is some sort of a different way to send this request to avoid being blocked by the CORS policy, or I'm stupid and overlooked something.

I have tried consulting the documentation, found no help there.

Comment: You should do the request via server side, not client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't do it this way is that you need to be keeping your key private - otherwise anyone could create a new project and start using your key on *their site* and you would get charged for it.  You *should not* be exposing your key to the frontend.

https://www.semrush.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-semrush-project-api/

> Once you find your API Key, you will want to keep this private from other unauthorized users of your account. This key is unique to you, making sure you are charged the necessary API units for any calls you make using your key.

What you need to do is make a request to *your server*, and have your server make another request to semrush, so that they key is never exposed.  Basically just don't make the request from the frontend and it should be fine.